# Can a reference prolong the lifetime of any member data of a class which is returned by a mamber function

Tags: c++, reference

```
class sample
{
  std::string mString;

public:
  void Set(const std::string &s)
  {
    mString = s;
  }

  //std::string Get() const
  const std::string& Get() const
  {
    return mString;
  }
};
```

Let's say I have such a class as above and now I use this class like this:

```
sample *p = new sample;
p->Set("abcdefg");
const std::string& ref = p->Get();
delete p;
p = nullptr;
std::cout << ref << std::endl;
```

As you see, the member function `Get` returns a reference, which is assigned to the outer reference `ref`. After that, the whole object is deleted.

However, it seems that this code works without any error.

I'm a little confused. It could run just because I'm lucky or it's the reference `ref` that prolongs the lifetime of the member variable `mString`?

Comment: 'Can a reference prolong the lifetime of any member data of a class': no, but the lifetime of the variable may not be what you think it is, and even if is the vestiges remaining may be sufficient to make your code work, even though it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user207421 So this is definitely an UB. My colleague told me that he has coded like this for a very long time... I'm shocked...

Comment: @Yves I really hope this is just a misunderstanding and your colleague meant a function returning by-value. Otherwise it is breaking basic rules about lifetime management in C++ and I would be surprised if he never had this cause random crashes before.

Comment: @user17732522 It's not a joke. But I think I may know why his code always works. We are working with gcc 5.4.0. Our compilation command contains the option `-O2`. It seems that this option will do some optimization, which makes `std::string Get() const` and `const std::string& Get() const` the same.

Comment: @Yves Make a debug build of the application with `-fsanitize=address` to find occurrences of similar issues. The address sanitizer will recognize this UB. Better to fix this before it crashes with the next compiler upgrade, random code modification or even worse generates wrong data. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/oPz8aMG34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, lifetime extension by reference binding applies only to temporary objects materialized from prvalues.

Objects created with `new` never have their lifetime extended past `delete`.

What you are seeing here is just a manifestation of undefined behavior. `ref` is dangling after `delete p;` and therefore reading from it in the `cout` statement has undefined behavior.

---

If `Get` was returning by-value (`std::string Get() const`), then it would be true that the temporary materialized from the return value of the function would have its lifetime extended to that of the reference `ref`.

And in that case the program behavior would be well-defined.

---

Similarly if the `sample` object had automatic storage duration, the reference would not extent its lifetime or the lifetime of one of its subobjects either:

```
/* DO NOT USE: Undefined behavior */

const std::string& ref = []() -> const std::string& {
    sample s;
    p.Set("abcdefg");
    return s->Get();
    // lifetime of s ends with function returning
}();

/* UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR */    
std::cout << ref << std::endl;
```

Here it is the lambda's return type that would need to be changed from `const std::string&` to `std::string` to avoid the UB. Only the first reference binding can extent lifetime and therefore changing the return type of `Get` would not be sufficient in this case.

Comment: The same question where the object of type `sample` is an automatic variable would be interesting. I'd love this answer to tackle this point even though it is not explicitly asked.

Comment: @YSC Like above maybe? With automatic storage duration this can't happen so easily if there isn't another function call intervening.

Comment: Exactly, I'm happy with it being explicitly said. I cannot upvote a second time but this is appreciated